# Adding attribute name to radio button using XSL-T

Tags: xml, xslt, radio-button

I've made an XSL-T file to transform an xml quiz into a form with tables, the problem is that as the questions are being created using recursive programming I can't add a name to them, so there's no way to know which question is which.

The XML file has elements like this one:

```
<question id="question2" filter="generic">
    <foo>What console do you like the most?</foo>
    <simple-election>
        <option>Playstation 4</option>
        <option>Nintendo Switch</option>
        <option>XBox One</option>
        <option></option>
    </simple-election>
</question>
```

And here is the XSL-T file:

```
<xsl:template match="simple-election">
<xsl:for-each select="option">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        <td><input type="radio"></input></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

(the others part of the file has the start of the form, the table, etc.)

My idea was to add something like this:

```
<td><input name="question/@id" type="radio"></input></td>
```

But I can' seem to get it working, any idea?

PS: I can show you the rest of the file if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<input name="{../../@id}" type="radio">
```

---

Or, to make it more efficient, capture the `id` in a variable:

```
<xsl:template match="simple-election">
    <xsl:variable name="question-id" select="../@id" />
```

then use it as:

```
<input name="{$question-id}" type="radio">
```

---

See [location paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev)  and [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#dt-attribute-value-template) for more details.

Comment: It works wonderfully, I'm pretty new to this lenguage and didn't know you could capture variables, thanks a lot.